# load files in the right order depending on their names

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
  return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== FALSE);
}

function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
  $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
  $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
  $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
  $fileList = array();
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
  }
  return $fileList;
}

foreach(rsearch("images/" . $directory . "", "_.*jpg_iU") as $file) {
  if(!endsWith($file, "title.jpg")) {
  echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
  }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow load .jpg files depending on their names? I have files names like that IMG_0001, IMG_0002 and so on. Is it possible to load them in that order?

Comment: I assume that rsearch is your own custom function? If that returns an array as would appear to be the case then surely you can sort the array prior to iterating through it to display the images?

Comment: @RamRaider Whoops I kind of forgot to put there those functions. And I really don't know how, someone from stackoverflow made it for me, which I'm really glad for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the array returned by `rsearch` is quite simple so `sort( $arr )` or `rsort( $arr )` should be useful. You could play around with both of them to see the results and modify your code to incoroporate them - such as:

```
$files=rsearch("images/" . $directory . "", "_.*jpg_iU");
sort( $files );
foreach( $files as $file ){
    /* rest of your code*/
}
```

or you could modify you rsearch function to incorporate the search before you return the results....

```
function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
  $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
  $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
  $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
  $fileList = array();
  foreach($files as $file) {
    $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
  }

  sort( $filelist );
  /* check the manual for the various flags you can set on the sort function */

  return $fileList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to have a look on php documentation and edit it to this `sort($files, SORT_REGULAR);` , but now it works like a charm.